# Operating on Multiple Layers in Flash CS6

Tags: flash, animation, adobe, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I'm new to flash, and I've made a few flash animations in Flash CS6, however some functions that I use very often are mind mindbogglingly repetitive because I simply cannot find a way to perform them on multiple layers at a time.

1. Is there a way to compress/expand multiple motion tweens at a time? I can increase the length of a certain tween on a certain layer one at a time, however I want to be simply be able to select multiple layers and drag them so I can compress/expand all of them at the same time. They are all lined up on the same frame.
2. Is there a way to copy/paste multiple properties at a time? I very often right click on a frame -> copy properties/paste properties, to help with looping and such. Problem is this has to be done individually for ever single layer, despite all my keyframes of all my layers being lined up on the same frame.
3. How do I adjust the keyframe of multiple layers at a time? When I select multiple symbols in my flash animation, I often want to drag them such that where they land, all those layers will get a new keyframe on the timeline and thus tween themselves to that position. However, half the time it just moves the base position of my entire tween, and the other half it works as intended, however I have no idea what properties control whether it actually works or not. How do I control this?
4. Can I reverse the keyframes of multiple layers at a time?
5. Is it possible to make my animation loop in a more natural fashion? Instead of having all the layers begin and end in the same position (often achieved through painstaking copy properties/paste properties), is it possible for me to tell flash to simply tween itself back to frame 1 over x frames?

Comment: From what I've seen, you either work with the limitations of editing things from the timeline, or you go the developer route and get absolute power! Muahahaha! ... If going the programming route I recommend http://www.greensock.com/timelinemax/ for any timeline type of animations

Comment: @Zeke with the Flash IDE at best you could build a few JSFL scripts using the Motion XML structure but it's not super straight forward and a bit hacky. The other option, as Todd mentioned, is using actionscript.